# How to atomically overwrite with a O_TMPFILE file?

Tags: c, linux

The below works but I want to clean it up. The man page give both linkat below as examples however not once have I gotten the first one to work. Using the second only works as long as the filename is unique which isn't true in my case so I use an intermediary name. I wanted to use rename so I can skip it but it complained about cross device problems. Is there a way I can improve this code? It seems weird to call linkat and immediately call rename afterwards

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd = open("./", O_TMPFILE | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }
    
    int len = write(fd, "data\n", 5);
    printf("Written %d bytes to %d\n", len, fd);
    const char myfile[] = "myfile";
    if (linkat(fd, "", AT_FDCWD, myfile, AT_EMPTY_PATH)) {
        perror("linkat");
        char buf[1024];
        snprintf(buf, 1024,  "/proc/self/fd/%d", fd);
        //if (linkat(AT_FDCWD, buf, AT_FDCWD, myfile, AT_SYMLINK_FOLLOW) < 0) {
        if (linkat(AT_FDCWD, buf, AT_FDCWD, "intermediaryName", AT_SYMLINK_FOLLOW) < 0) {
            perror("linkat backup failed");
            return 1;
        }
        if (rename("intermediaryName", myfile) < 0) {
            perror("rename");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Success\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that's not really important to the question. All I'm saying is I tried rename and couldn't figure it out without an intermediary filename with linkat. Chances are I had a typo or used an invalid flag

Comment: Do you have `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH` capability by providing the define `_GNU_SOURCE` in your compile string -- otherwise read carefully the documentation under `AT_EMPTY_PATH` in the man-page.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `O_TMPFILE` means `open("./")` doesn't open the current directory; it opens an unnamed temporary file on the same file system as the current directory. If the file isn't given a name it is automatically deleted when the descriptor is closed.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - thank you. I read that part of the man-page several times and it still wasn't entirely clear.

Comment: After digging further, the crux is still the same, before you can use `linkat()` with `AT_EMPTY_PATH`,  "The caller must have the `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH` capability in order to use this flag." See [man 7 capabilities](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html). Disto depending there is a collection of shell tools that accompanies `libcap` that can go by names `libcap-progs` or `libcap2-bin`, etc.. that provides simple tools like `capsh` to display what the current and bounding sets of capabilities are and whether they are available. Both black and white-hat tools.

Comment: Helpful link [How do I use capsh: I am trying to run an unprivileged ping, with minimal capabilities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/196483/197080)